# Similar Proofs using ZF

Tags: set-theory

I have been given two question. Both require the use of the Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms.

One asks to prove that there is no set a such that $a= \{a \}$. 
The other asks to prove that there is no set $b$ such that $b \in b$.

What is the difference between the two questions? I proved the first one by contradiction by letting $a = \{a\}$ and then defining $b := \{a\}$ and showed that because they are not disjoint $a$ cannot exist. I feel like the second question has the same proof.

Comment: In your brief description of your proof, you neglected to point out that $a$ is the *only* member of $a$ (or $b$ if you wish). Without that, you don't get the contradiction you seek. (Hint: There is nothing wrong in a set and *some* of its members not being disjoint.)

Comment: In my proof after my definitions, I said by the axiom of regularity   since a $\in$ b then a and b must be disjoint. If their intersect does not equal the empty set as it does in this case, the set breaks the axiom and therefore cannot exist, because a and b are not disjoint.

Comment: If $b=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ and $a=\{\emptyset\}$, then $a\in b$, yet $a$ and $b$ are not disjoint; does this contradict the axiom of regularity?

Comment: I see what you are saying. based on the axiom, a is nonempty. Since a is the only element in a, it must be the element that is least based on the axiom and the well ordering principle, and to be the case it must be disjoint but this does not exist for the case a = {a}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first question you are asked to show that a specific type of set cannot exist: namely one that has itself *as its only* element.  The second is broader, asking to show that no set can have itself as an element (even if it has other elements).

Of course, the latter directly implies the former (if no set can have itself as an element, then there cannot be a set which has itself as its only element), but the reverse is not quite as immediate

Comment: I see. So it seems to me for the method that I used that the only difference in the proof would be how I define my sets in the beginning. Is that correct?

Comment: I think that the reverse is false, by the way. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: @BobEccain: Pretty much.  Your proof will again rely on the Axiom of Regularity, so picking out the correct contradictory set at the beginning is the important step.

Comment: @Asaf: I'm trying to think of this as well.  Even if the reverse is false it is still "not quite as immediate".   ;-)

Comment: Oh, of course. The common way of countering regularity is to start with models with atoms then using permutations to take any extensional relation on the atom and making it into $\in$ of the permutation model (this is due to Mostowski, I believe, and how I was taught that regularity is independent from the other axioms). And I think that one can easily concoct a relation where it's always true that $a\neq\{a\}$ but still $a\in a$ for some $a$.